# scoreboard data check use of associative arrays as storage structure

Tags: specman

Could you please someone help me in coding a scoreboard storage structure using associative arrays. The output transaction are coming out of order. Is there also a better way to implement the data checks?

Comment: The question is rather broad. Do you mean you want to know how to implement and associative array in `e`?

Answer (score 1):

`e` doesn't have associative arrays in the traditional sense. What it does have, however, are keyed lists. Here's an example:

```
struct array_entry {
  key : string;
  val : uint;
};
```

First we need to define how an entry in the keyed list looks like. We model this as a struct that contains the key and the value pair. Also note, there's nothing stopping us from having multiple value fields indexed by the same key.

```
extend sys {
  !assoc_array: list(key: key) of array_entry;

  run() is also {
    // adding an entry
    var s : array_entry = new;
    s.key = "foo";
    s.val = 0xdead_beef;
    assoc_array.add(s);

    // check if an entry exists
    print assoc_array.key_exists("bar");

    // get an entry
    if assoc_array.key_exists("foo") {
      print assoc_array.key("foo").val using hex;
    };
  };
};
```

We define a keyed list of this type using the `key` field as the key. This means that the elements can be indexed by position (the order in which they are added to the list), but also by key.

Have a look at the keyed-list chapter in the documentation for more info.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for. I tried to implement keyed list this way:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. That's what I was looking for. I tried to implement keyed list this way:

```
extend sys {

  !a : list (key:it) of uint(bits:4);

  run() is also {

  var b : uint = 0;
  for i from 0 to 10 {
    a.add(b);
    b = b+2;
  };
  if a.key_exists(4) {
    print a;
    print a.key(4);
    print a.key_index(4);
    print a.key_index(7);
    };
  };
};
```

The output I get is:
        a =  (11 items, dec): 4  2  0  14 12 10  8   6  4  2  0     .0
        a.key(4) = 4
        a.key_index(4) = 2
        a.key_index(7) = -1

Clearly, the item at key 4 is 8 not 4. Do I understand wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Rahul,

The results you get seem to be accurate.
the list is a[0] = 0, a[1] = 2, a[2] = 4, ...

a.key(4) returns the item that its key is "4" (the item is "4", of course...)

a.key_index(4) returns the index of the item that its value is 4 - 2 (a[2] == 4)

a.key_index(7) returns the index of the item that its value is 7. since there is no item that its key is 7, the result is UNDEF

I recommend checking out the uvm_scoreboard. It's an open source in specman/uvm/uvm_lib. It also uses key list.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not confuse between the key and the index. In a keyed list in ***e***, each entry has both.

When you declare a keyed list with `(key: it)`, it means that each entry's key is its own value. So, `a.key(4) = 4`, and so on.
On the other hand, you are right that the entry at index 4 is 8. It means that `a[4] = 8` or `a.key_index(8) = 4`.

In other words, each entry in a keyed list still has an index just like in a regular (non-keyed) list. But the index and they key are completely unrelated. When you add a new entry to the list (using `add()`), it gets added to the next index (just like with non-keyed lists), and it **also** get the relevant key.